# Xamarin: Issue when TargetSdkVersion set to API 31 in manifest

Tags: xamarin.android, android-12

By refer to [Xamarin.Android 12.0 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/12/12.0), I set TargetFramework to Android 12 and I able to deploy project without any problem.
However, I encountered following error when I set `android:targetSdkVersion` to *API 31* in android manifest.

```
ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl204773411.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #84): com.urbanairship.accengage.PackageUpdatedReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

This happens only when `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 31 and deployed to physical device/emulator with android 12. I already added `android:exported="true"` to MainActivity class and classes that use intent filters. Could anyone advice me how to resolve this?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.myapp.simulation" android:versionName="1.0.30" android:versionCode="110" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application tools:replace="android:allowBackup" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon" android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupOnly="false" android:label="Sample App">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, the PackageUpdatedReceiver in your project doesn't set a value for the android:exported. So you can try to set a value by the two following ways.

1. Set it in the attribute of the BroadCastReceiver:

`[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true)]`

2. Set it into the `application` label in the AndroidManifest.xml:

Edit: For android 12, all the Services, BroadCastReceivers, Activity classes need to declare the value for the `android:exported`. So update the three part sdk to the last version.

Comment: Basically we use only 'intent-filters' and no 'BroadcastReceiver' in our project. And, we already added android:exported="true" to the classes that using intent-filters.
It's strange that this issue happened only in physical devices/emulator with android 12

Comment: But what the `com.urbanairship.accengage.PackageUpdatedReceiver`  in the error message is? @WeiLoonWong

Comment: Is it a service , a BroadcastReceiver or a activity? If so, it also need to add the `android:exported="true"`. @Wei Loon Wong

Comment: urbanairship is a third-party Android SDK for pushing notification.

Comment: Can you provide the nuget package name? I will do a test on my device. In addition, it seems difficult to add `android:exported="true"` to a three party sdk. @WeiLoonWong

Comment: urbanairship.android.accengage, urbanairship.android.core, urbanairship.android.fcm
These are 3 NuGet for Airship

Comment: Do you use the last version(16.1.1) of them? I had test it and there is no error.@WeiLoonWong

Comment: No luck, app crashed with edited answer above. I'll update the packages to latest version and test again

Comment: Does it work now?@WeiLoonWong

Comment: It works now after I update airship, firebase and GooglePlayServices nuget packages to latest version.